# Select in loop don't ask for input

Tags: bash, select, reply

I'm trying to ask a question in a loop (ask confirmation to treat each file in a directory, for instance).

This piece of code work perfectly :

```
PS3="Dummy question ? "
select CHOICE_MADE in "Ans1" 'Ans2' 'Ans3'; do
    if [[ -n ${CHOICE_MADE} ]]; then
        printf "Choice made : %s\n" "${CHOICE_MADE}"
        break;
    fi
done
```

I need to loop this question (Note I name the variable in loop, to avoid using default $REPLY variable) :

```
while read -r TOTO; do
    PS3="Dummy question ? "
    select CHOICE_MADE in Ans1 Ans2 Ans3; do
        if [[ -n ${CHOICE_MADE} ]]; then
            printf "Choice made : %s\n" "${CHOICE_MADE}"
            break;
        fi
    done
done < <(echo Step1 Step2)
```

Select doesn't prompt anything.

I don't want to use whiptail (which masks script previous output), dialog (need to be installed on debian) or any gui.

I know I could use read to solve my problem, but I would like keeping select loop.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd use a `for` loop: `for f in step1 step2; do ... done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to note two things in order to make it works.

#### 1) Bad use of `stdin`

First of all, passing `< (echo Step1 Step2)` to your `while` cycle, you are making use of `stdin` and that's why the prompt does not wait for any input at all (It already has it!).

You can get rid of it by using [file descriptors](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
exec 3< <(echo Step1 Step2) ### Create fd "3" and put output of echo in it
while read -r TOTO <&3; do
    PS3="Dummy question ? "
    select CHOICE_MADE in Ans1 Ans2 Ans3; do
        if [[ -n ${CHOICE_MADE} ]]; then
            printf "Choice made : %s\n" "${CHOICE_MADE}"
            break
        fi
    done
done
exec 3>&- ### clean fd 3
```

I left unchanged the rest of code.

#### 2) Bad use of `read`

Another thing you have to think of, is that `read -r` will read line by line what you give him, and a simple `echo Step1 Step2` will produce only a single line, so you will cycle through just a single occurrence.

In order to get rid of this unwanted behaviour you will have to use other solutions.

One solution I can think of at the moment is [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
exec 3<< EOF
Step1
Step2
EOF
while read -r TOTO <&3; do
    PS3="Dummy question ? "
    select CHOICE_MADE in Ans1 Ans2 Ans3; do
        if [[ -n ${CHOICE_MADE} ]]; then
            printf "Choice made: %s\n" "${CHOICE_MADE}"
            break
        fi
    done
done
exec 3>&- ### clean fd 3
```

Note that using several heredoc is not advisable and best practices suggest to use actual files instead, because a script should contains logic, not data.

Comment: Instead of the `exec` commands, you could also just put `3<whatever` after the outer `done` command (e.g. `done 3<< EOF ...`)

Comment: Thanks, first point worked perfectly, I learned something here ! For second point, I actually took an example, the real code was a find ... -print, so read was not an issue there.

Comment: You are right, read is not an issue, it's the combination of read with a single echo, because of the one-line output of echo... @Gordon yes, every redirect should work, even a pipe or a file, I am just more comfortable using a fd [: